# Abstract child state and grandchild state in angular with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, parent-child, angular-ui

Have had issues trying to implement an abstract child state that belongs to an abstract parent state and has child states itself.  Something like the following:

```
.state('parent', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent/parent.html',
  controller: 'parent-controller',    
})

.state(parent.child', {
  abstract: true
  url: '/child',
  templateUrl: 'parent/child/child.html',
  controller: 'child-controller',
})

.state(parent.child.grandchild', {
  url: '/grandchild',
  templateUrl: 'parent/child/grandchild/grandchild.html',
  controller: 'grandchild-controller',
})
```

So far I haven't been able to get this to work, nor have I found any answers that deal with this question.  The documentation only seems to cover parent-child, but doesn't get into grandchildren.

Is this possible with UI-Router in angular?  Does my failure have to do with using dot notation when declaring the state name?

Comment: A common mistake would be not having `ui-view` in either parent or child template. If you have nothing to put in `child.html`, you can target parent's `ui-view` by using `views: { "@parent": {...} }` in grandchild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This concept should be working. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b1Se1cL2LRB7tHF1ynLK?p=preview)

With just a few fixes of your typos

```
  .state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/parent',
    templateUrl: 'parent/parent.html',
    controller: 'parent-controller',
  })

  .state('parent.child', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/child',
    templateUrl: 'parent/child/child.html',
    controller: 'child-controller',
  })

  .state('parent.child.grandchild', {
      url: '/grandchild',
      templateUrl: 'parent/child/grandchild/grandchild.html',
      controller: 'grandchild-controller',
    })
```

to be sure we do have controllers

```
.controller('parent-controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {}])
.controller('child-controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {}])
.controller('grandchild-controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {}])
```

And with each parent having a target for its child

```
...
<div ui-view></div>
...
```

These links must work

```
<a href="#/parent/child/grandchild">    
<a ui-sref="parent.child.grandchild">
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/b1Se1cL2LRB7tHF1ynLK?p=preview)

Comment: I know this is an old topic but I really want to say thank you. It's incredible how much it's helped me after hours of finding an answer to this.